# :not() psuedoclass for httml[lang] not working

Tags: css, sass

Trying to make a more dynamic css so do certain styling for non english html pages, instead of having to add a css rule each time a language page is added.

Trying to turn this...

```
html[lang='de-DE'],html[lang='pt-br'],html[lang='ja'] {
    // bootstrap blocks flexbox fix
    .col-12.d-flex > div:first-child {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

To work with this...

```
:not(html[lang='en-US']) {
    // bootstrap blocks flexbox fix
    .col-12.d-flex > div:first-child {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view `:not()` as a selector specificator. It requires to refer to a selector, to then specify it.
If we apply this to your example, we would take `html` as the selector and `html[lang=en-US]` to be passed into the specificator, resulting in this:

```
html:not(html[lang=en-US]) {
  //content
}
```

We can acctually further shorten it, since `[lang=en-US]` is a [functioning selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) itself:

```
html:not([lang=en-US]) {
  //content
}
```